Cannot access classes in custom common sourceset from an android build variant in a KMP module
I have a question regarding advanced project structure.
I need different variants of my multiplatform shared library : privateVariant and publicVariant.
Here is my custom configuration (module “shared”) :
kotlin {
    withSourcesJar(publish = false)

    androidTarget()

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
        }
        val commonPrivateVariant by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
        }
        val androidPrivateVariant by creating {
            dependsOn(commonPrivateVariant)
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
        }
    }
}

android {
    flavorDimensions += "sdk"
    productFlavors {
        create("privateVariant") {
            dimension = "sdk"
        }
    }
}

And my app gradle file which uses my private variant :
android {
    defaultConfig {
        missingDimensionStrategy("sdk", "privateVariant")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":shared"))
}

Problem is : I cannot access classes in commonPrivateVariant from androidPrivateVariant. Is it possible and how ?
